# Syntax help needed: Taxonomy Query

Tags: taxonomy, query

I have a template called `taxonomy-book_style.php` to handle all the terms in book_style. On it I just have a simple loop

`<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>`

I would like to order my posts by the meta key value found in the meta_key tf_book_sort

So far I've tried these but they do not work:

```
<?php 
query_posts( $query_string . 'orderby=meta_value&meta_key=tf_book_sort&order=ASC' );?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post('meta_key=tf_book_sort&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC'); ?>

<?php 
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'book_style')),
'meta_key' => 'tf_book_sort',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'DESC'
);?>
<?php query_posts ($args);?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

The nested arrays are confusing, can someone please suggest a proper synatx to accomplish sorting these posts by a meta key value?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, let's just forget `query_posts` exists. there's no good reason to use it, ever.

the best way to do this is via the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action in your theme's `functions.php`. you don't have to set any taxonomy parameters, those are already set on a taxonomy archive page, you just need meta key and orderby:

```
function wpa65258_tax_meta_orderby( $query ) {
    if ( is_tax( 'book_style' ) && is_main_query() ) : // edit -> added is_main_query()
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'tf_book_sort' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    endif;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa65258_tax_meta_orderby' );
```

This assumes your meta value is numeric. if it's not, change `orderby` to `meta_value` instead of `meta_value_num`.

Then in your template, just do the normal loop:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

etc..

Comment: Hmm, that still gives me nothing. It also strangely causes all my post_types to disappear from the front end.

Comment: I tested and it's working in TwentyEleven with the register taxonomy and post type code from Codex. You likely have an issue with some other code in your theme or a plugin.

Comment: Is there a solution using query posts? It dosen't have to be pretty.

Comment: a better solution is to learn to [debug your queries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) and figure out where your errors are.

Comment: Debug only returned two sidebar errors, which I fixed. Function still gives me no listings, and still removes my post_types. Its like its over-riding the normal loop on that template for some reason. Thanks for your response and the link to that plugin.

Comment: sorry should have mentioned, if you have multiple loops on a single template you should also check `is_main_query`, see edit.

Comment: Nope that still gives me nothing. I also only have the one loop. I think this time around I'm just going to have to do something manual-ish. But thanks for replying. And I'll look more into is_tax.